# Invertibility in $\mathbb{Z}_m$.

Tags: proof-verification, modular-arithmetic

I believe I have figured out this proof, though I'm hoping someone can look it over for style and notation. In particular, in modular arithmetic, I find myself going back and forth between equivalence, $\equiv$, and a standard equals sign. I believe the distinction is that the latter follows from some kind of algebra, the former from equivalence in a modulus. I've been stringing these together in equation chains, though, which I'm unsure is valid. Here's the theorem and my proof.

Theorem: If $x$ and $y$ are invertible in $\mathbb{Z}_m$, then $xy$ and $x^{-1}$ are also invertible.

Proof: If $x$ and $y$ are invertible, $\exists a, b$ s.t. $xa \equiv \ \text{(mod $m$)}$ and $yb \equiv  1 \ \text{(mod $m$)}$. Then, 
\begin{align*}
\left(xy\right)\left(ab\right) & = \left(xy\right)\left(ba\right) \\
& = x \left(yb\right) a \\
& \equiv x \cdot 1 \cdot a \ \text{(mod $m$)} \\
& = xa \\
& \equiv 1 \ \text{(mod $m$)}
\end{align*}
and, thus, $ab$  is the inverse of $xy$.

$x^{-1}$ is trivially invertible, as $xa = xx^{-1} = x^{-1} x \equiv 1 \ \text{(mod $m$)}$, with an inverse of $x$.

So, my questions are:
(1) How do these proofs look?
(2) Is the equality chain valid? In other words, can I conclude that $yb \equiv 1 \ \text{(mod $m$)}$, and then continue the chain with, say, algebraic simplification and then introduce another equivalence? This might be trivial, though I'm not too familiar with the conventions of modular arithmetic. It seems that some people write these with a standard equality sign but indicate which modulus they're working in.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start wth $ba$ instead of $ab$. In noncommutative contexts, $(xy)^{-1}=y^{-1}x^{-1}$.

Comment: Everything looks good! Yes, I mix $=$ and $\equiv$ regularly; I think it helps the reader understand what steps are taking place.

Comment: Thank you both. I appreciate this. One quick question, though: am I incorrect in thinking that elements in $\mathbb{Z}_m$ follow a commutative law (since the integers do)? I'm sure this isn't the case in, say, group theory, which I'm slowly working my way through. But I thought this didn't make too much of a difference in modular arithmetic; but I will surely revise the proof, if needed.

Comment: Looks fine to me.  $Z_m$ is abelian,  so ab=ba...